# OnViewModelSet - Nullreference exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, nullreferenceexception

I am working on an android app with xamarin and MvvmCross. I have an activity which inherits from a baseactivity. In debug, and also in release mode, everything seems to work. But sometimes my error-tracer collects the following exception.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object]

It seems, that my viewmodel is not set. But I can't find a Problem in my code. It's everytime the same.

Stacktrace:

> at MyProject.Views.MyActivity.OnViewModelSet () <0x0016c> at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivity.set_ViewModel
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel) <0x0002b> at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.IMvxView,System.Func'1)
>   <0x000e7> at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView,Android.OS.Bundle)
>   <0x0020f> at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled
>   (object,Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs'1)
>   <0x00103> at (wrapper delegate-invoke)
>   System.EventHandler'1>.invoke_void_object_TEventArgs
>   (object,Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs'1)
>   <0x000c7> at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise
>   (System.EventHandler'1>,object,Android.OS.Bundle)
>   <0x0004b> at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid.Views.MvxEventSourceActivity.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x00057> at
>   MyProject.Views.MyBaseActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0001b>
>   at MyProject.Views.MyActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0001b>
>   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0006b> at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   object.e71855e6-3740-4345-be34-e01a409ee7f6 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   <0x0004b>

I think the exception is inside the [`MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate`](https://github.com/object/MvvmCross.DesignTimeVM/blob/master/DesignerError/MvvmCross/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Views/MvxViewExtensionMethods.cs#L18). But I have no idea, what I can do against this problem.

Why this error occurs?

Comment: This could be caused by rotation or coming from the background. What version of MvvmCross are you running? And are you using fragments.

Comment: I am using MvvmCross 3.5.1. And no, I do not use any fragments in the Project. The rotation is not allowed (and so not possible) on this activity, so this can't be the reason (as far as I know)

Comment: And what about coming from the background? Could you try to use MvvmCross 4.0? There are many improvements, and this could be fixed.

Comment: I can't reproduce the exception, that's my big Problem. I tried loading the view from background, but I didn't get any exception. Thats a BETA right? Do you know when the public release is?

Comment: It's beta, but on the other hand it is quite stable. I can't say any exact date because it still is in active development. I would just give it a try if you can.